# Can't bridge two edge loops on single mesh

Tags: mesh, edges

I am unable to bridge two edge loops and get the error shown here:
[image]

This is a single mesh and both loops have 260 vertices. Can anyone think of a reason this would happen?

The blend file is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kd4YI_6a5K11jvba5c35SsD9wGTWpXDe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Maybe not the same amount of vertices for each loop.

Comment: your topology is not good, I don't know why it make the bridge fail, but if you select all your vertices and Merge By Distance (20mm) you'll be able to bridge.

Comment: Screenshot appears to show an odd number of edges.